# Call requests min level of 16

Tags: android, background, android-framelayout

I want to change the background of my framelayout (which holds all my pages!) by:

```
FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
    fl.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.juraquiz_app_background));
```

but apparently I cant. Is there a way to do it, so its compatible with APIs lower than 16?

Answer (score 1):

for API's lower that 16 you can use [setBackgroundDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)

Answer (score 1):

Use different methods for different APIs:

```
final Drawable drw = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.juraquiz_app_background);
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16)
{
    fl.setBackgroundDrawable(drw);
}
else
{
    fl.setBackground(drw);
}
```

You will need to add an annotation to your method (or to your class, if you prefer) to get rid of Lint warnings:
**@SuppressLint("NewApi")**

Comment: then it wont let me compile it, it says my project contains an error

Comment: What error? Maybe it's a warning stating NEWAPI...? Just add an annotation: **@SuppressLint("NewApi")**